# Google maps rectangle click event as $mdDialog targetEvent option

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-material

Google Maps passes me a click event whenever I click on a drawn rectangle. Besides some extra info, there's a MouseEvent object. Unfortunately, even though I pass this object as targetEvent option to $mdDialog service, the dialog opens from the window center. Any ideas where's the problem?

Comment: Yep, can't get it to work either - https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/YWZRpQ. Must be something about the MouseEvent. Looking at it in the console it is slightly different to the event in the example - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog